# Linux show verbose/technical file information

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, filesystems, gnu

Is there a GNU/Linux command that shows verbose information about a file?
 Something that outputs all the (raw) technical information the filesystem has about the file, e.g. blocks used, exact create and modified timestamps, etc.

Comment: This question is a more general computer usage question than it is programming-related so it’s not really on topic for StackOverflow.
It would be more appropriate for [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/). (`stat`)

Comment: Agreed @AnthonyGeoghegan - Can I move it over there? Or does it require special permissions?

Comment: AIUI, moderators can migrate questions if you flag it for them. Most people simply copy and paste the question content and then self-delete the original but in this case that wouldn't be a good idea, as agc has already comprehensively answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat`.  Example:

```
echo foo > /tmp/bar ; stat /tmp/bar
```

Output:

```
  File: '/tmp/bar'
  Size: 4           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 80bh/2059d  Inode: 87          Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      woo)   Gid: ( 1000/      woo)
Access: 2017-05-21 23:34:23.770302257 -0400
Modify: 2017-05-21 23:34:23.770302257 -0400
Change: 2017-05-21 23:34:23.770302257 -0400
 Birth: -
```

I don't think `stat` gives *all* blocks used.  `hdparm` can do that, almost... it shows sectors, not blocks; also the sector addresses are relative to the hard drive, not the file system:

```
hdparm --fibmap /tmp/bar
```

Output:

```
/tmp/bar:
 filesystem blocksize 4096, begins at LBA 253288448; assuming 512 byte sectors.
 byte_offset  begin_LBA    end_LBA    sectors
           0  253559088  253559095          8
```

For file system blocks there's `filefrag`:

```
filefrag -v /tmp/bar
```

Output:

```
Filesystem type is: ef53
File size of /tmp/bar is 4 (1 block of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..       0:      33830..     33830:      1:             last,eof
/tmp/bar: 1 extent found
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! D'oh, of course `stat` - I've used it before but it slipped my mind. Thanks for the other commands as well!